# Backspace and Ctrl + c (Copy) does not work for input field (FireFox)

Tags: jquery, html, regex, frontend, semantic-ui

I have a form developed using semantic UI input field. my requirements are that the input field should only accept numerics, eliminate whitespaces and should allow to copy from the input field <kbd>ctrl +c</kbd>.

I did some research and this jQuery code seems to meet to my requirements since it works well in Chrome. however FireFox does not allow me to either use the backspace nor use copy function.

This is the jQuery code am using;

```
$("#checker").on("keypress keyup blur", function(event) {

  $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d ].+/, ""));
  if ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

How can I make it work in FireFox just like it works in chrome ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use single `regex` pattern to allow numeric only and there is no need to prevent other key numbers, It work on Chrome and FireFox and etc.

```js
$("#checker").on("keypress input blur", function(event) {

  var value = $(this).val();
  value = value.replace(/\D+/, '');
  $(this).val(value);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="checker" />
```

Comment: Works great. just the answer i've been looking for , thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can detect the 'ctrl' key then detect the 'c' key and in that case, let the event occur as intended. Otherwise you prevent the action.

Here is a non-polished example that works in FireFox. I am sure it could be improved:

```
   $(function () {
        var ctrlDown = false,
            ctrlKey = 17,
            cKey = 67,
            backSpaceKey = 8;

        $("#checker").on("keydown keyup blur", function (event) {

            // Checks if 'ctrl' key was pressed and raises the flags
            if (event.which == ctrlKey) {
                ctrlDown = true;
            }

            // Checks if 'c' key was pressed, resets the ctrl key and continues to execute the copy action
            if (event.which == cKey) {
                ctrlDown = false;
            }
            else if ((event.which < 48 || event.which > 57) && (event.which != backSpaceKey)) {
                // Cancel any key and reset all flags
                event.preventDefault();
                ctrlDown = false;
            }

            $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/[^\d ].+/, ""));
        });
    });
```

If you want other keys, (such as arrow keys), to be excluded from the prevention then you can add them to the 'if' clause where I cheked that the 'backspace' key is pressed, then I do not prevent the action.

**You could also use Regex in order to filter only numbers and not deal with all the other keys. It is up to you. I think the Regex solution is much better.**

Comment: The code worked great but i found a glitch during copying ( does not allow me to copy the input to another input field).. thank you for the help btw.

Comment: As I said, it was just a small example to show that it can be done :)
Glad to be helpful!

Comment: yes it was helpful. i really appreciate your response :).. have a great day.